# WHERE AND in Sqlite Statement

Tags: iphone, sql, xcode, sqlite

I am having a problem combining two WHERE statements in the following SQL statement :

```
query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"SELECT Name, Description,Postcode,AddressLine1, ImageURL, Free, Area, OpeningTimes, NearestTube, Cost,UniqueID, URL, Number, FirstLetter FROM MainDetails WHERE Free ='Y' AND FirstLetter = '%@%'",tmpLike];
```

I want to say where Free is equal to Y and FirstLetter is equal to tmplike, however the above is not working.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS REMOVE % FROM LAST

```
query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"SELECT Name, Description,Postcode,AddressLine1, ImageURL, Free, Area, OpeningTimes, NearestTube, Cost,UniqueID, URL, Number, FirstLetter FROM MainDetails WHERE Free ='Y' AND FirstLetter = '%@'",tmpLike];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using a wildcard so you want `LIKE` not equality (=);

```
... WHERE Free ='Y' AND FirstLetter LIKE '%@%'"
```

Comment: for better performance:... WHERE Free ='Y' AND FirstLetter LIKE '@%'".

Answer (score 0):

try with escape char '/'

```
 query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"SELECT Name, Description,Postcode,AddressLine1, ImageURL, Free, Area, OpeningTimes, NearestTube, Cost,UniqueID, URL, Number, FirstLetter FROM MainDetails WHERE Free ='Y' AND FirstLetter = '%@\%'",tmpLike];
```

Comment: First u try with Sqlite Browser or some other tool and use tat query

Comment: do u want ur FirstLetter coloumn value  exactly match to tmpLike

Answer (score 0):

use this one it work fine

```
query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"SELECT Name, Description,Postcode,AddressLine1, ImageURL, Free, Area, OpeningTimes, NearestTube, Cost,UniqueID, URL, Number, FirstLetter FROM MainDetails WHERE Free ='Y' AND FirstLetter LIKE '%@ %%'",tmpLike];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply brackets ?

```
... WHERE (Free ='Y') AND (FirstLetter LIKE '%@')",tmpLike];
```